# telethon ошибка PhoneCodeExpiredError

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram, бот, telethon

При вводе смс-кода вылетает ошибка PhoneCodeExpiredError
Если делать просто await client.start(phone), то ошибок нет, но мне нужно чтобы пользователь вводил код через бот

```
client = TelegramClient('Loipeef', api_id, api_hash)
@dp.message(F.text.startswith('/connect'))
async def cmd_start(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    # Получаем текст сообщения и разделяем его на части по пробелу
    text = message.text.strip()
    parts = text.split(' ')
    
    if len(parts) == 1:
        # Пользователь отправил только команду /connect, отправляем инструкцию
        await message.answer(MESSAGES['first_connection'], parse_mode='Markdown')
    elif len(parts) == 2:
        phone = parts[1]
        await state.update_data(phone = phone)
        # Попытка авторизации
        try:
            await message.reply(MESSAGES['phone_handler'])
            
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
            
            # Авторизуемся с использованием сессии, связанной с аккаунтом пользователя
            await client.connect()
            await message.answer('Please enter the login code sent to telegram app or sms (no spaces).\n\nFor example, your login code is 123456, then enter mycode123456')
            await client.send_code_request(phone)
            await state.set_state(Form.first_connection)
        except PhoneNumberInvalidError:
            await message.answer("❌ The phone number is invalid.")

# Тут будет состояние обрабатывающие сообщение
@dp.message(Form.first_connection)
async def cmd_phone(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    data = await state.get_data()
    phone = data['phone']
    code = message.text
    
    await client.sign_in(phone, code)
```